# How does this function works?

Tags: javascript

My question is how this function works, what I don't understand is the return part `yell(n-1) + "a"` what result I expected was `3a` but the result was `hiyaaaa`. I can't figure out how.

### Function code

```
var ninja = { 
  yell: function yell(n){ 
    return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
  } 
};
ninja.yell(4); //returns hiyaaaa
```

Comment: > "what I don't understand is the return part `yell(n-1) + "a"` "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yell` is a recursive function. When you call it with 4, it calls itself with 3 (4 - 1), which in turn calls itself with 2 (3 - 1), etc., as long as `n` is `> 0`.

The reason that `yell` is available to be called in this way is that the person writing the code wrote a *named function expression*:

```
yell: function yell(n){ 
  return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
}
```

What that does is create a function with the name `yell`, and assign it to the *property* `yell` on the object `ninja`. The property and the function happen to have the same name, but there's no reason they have to, it could have been:

```
yell: function foo(n){ 
  return n > 0 ? foo(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
}
```

`yell` (the unqualified symbol), or `foo` in my example above, is in scope within the function because it's the function's name.

It's worth a side-note here that named function expressions don't quite work correctly on IE8 and earlier (although that particular example would still work); more: [*Double take*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html)

Comment: Very good explanation, very useful note and provided a good quality source if more information needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

`yell(n-1)+"a"` calls the function again with a slightly lower value of `n`, and attaches an `a` to whatever the recursed call returns. In this case, you get this chain:

```
ninja.yell(4)
yell(3)+"a"
(yell(2)+"a")+"a"
((yell(1)+"a")+"a")+"a"
(((yell(0)+"a")+"a")+"a")+"a"
((("hiy"+"a")+"a")+"a")+"a"
"hiyaaaa"
```

Although, personally I'd rewrite the function like so:

```
ninja = {
    yell: function(n) {return "hiy"+new Array(n+1).join("a");}
};
```

Comment: Is the function I have shared here like a loop? I know how to make a function etc. but why I didn't knew how that's work, is it so difficult to "encrypt" this function when you didn't saw something like this before? I just though the result will be `3`.

Answer (score 1):

```
return n > 0 ? yell(n - 1) + "a" : "hiy";
```

`yell(n - 1)` will be executed *before* concatenating it with `"a"`. That means as it recurses (and `n` becomes smaller), it will eventually return `"hiy"` with the other `"a"`s concatenated along with it from the previous calls.

Answer (score 1):

It is recursive function, invoking itself until n==0, works OK.